# Variable adding and subtracting/randomizing problems

Tags: python, variables

```
#Variables
enemy=['Dummy','Ghost','Warrior','Zombie','Skeleton']
current_enemy=random.choice(enemy)
enemy_health=randint(1,100)
dmg=randint(0,50)
current_enemy_health=enemy_health-dmg

#Functions

def enemy_stats(current_enemy_health):
    if current_enemy_health<=0:
        print(current_enemy,"died.")
    if current_enemy_health>0:
        dmg=randint(0,50)
        current_enemy_health=enemy_health-dmg
        print(current_enemy,"has",current_enemy_health,"health left.")

#Meeting an enemy - Attack / Defend Option
def encounter(current_enemy):
    print(name,"encountered a",current_enemy,"with",current_enemy_health,"health.","What do you do?")
    print("Attack? or Defend?")

def battle():
    encounter(current_enemy)
    #Attack Or Defend?
    choice=input("What do you do?")
    if choice!="Attack" or choice!="Defend": #If the choice isn't attack then ask again
        print("Do you attack or defend?")
        choice=input("What do you do?")
    #Say correct sentence depending on what you do.
    if choice=="Attack": #If the choice was attack then do a random number of dmg to it
        print(name,choice+"s",current_enemy,".","You deal",dmg,"damage","to it.")
        enemy_stats(current_enemy_health)
    if choice=="Defend": #If ... to it
        print(name,choice+"s.")

    #Check to see if the enemy is still alive
    while current_enemy_health>1:
        #Attack Or Defend?
        choice=input("What do you do?")
        if choice!="Attack" or choice!="Defend": #If the choice isn't attack then ask again
            print("Do you attack or defend?")
            choice=input("What do you do?")
        #Say correct sentence depending on what you do
        if choice=="Attack": #If the choice was attack then do a random number of dmg to it
            print(name,choice+"s",current_enemy,".","You deal",dmg,"damage","to it.")
            enemy_stats(current_enemy_health)
        if choice=="Defend": #If ... to it
            print(name,choice+"s.")

    #Checks to see if the enemy is dead
    if current_enemy_health<=0:
        print(name,"successfully killed a",current_enemy)

battle(
```

)

So i'm making a text-based RPG game. All going well but there is one thing I can't fix, i've tried a lot of things to try and fix the problem, basically when you encounter and enemy it spawns with a random amount of health. You then hit it for some damage. 'Zombie with 20 health spawned. What will you do?' I attack and say I deal 9 damage. What happens is that the health just goes to a random number instead of 20-9. Or say I did 21 damages. What happens this time is that the health once again goes to a random number instead of 20-21 and dieing. Basically what I can't manage to fix is the health-dmg part. I haven't managed to see if the health<0 works as I can never get the enemy to 0 health.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: well, you calculate `current_enemy_health=enemy_health-dmg` and `dmg=randint(0,50)`, so no wonder it's a random amount... btw. you'd profit applying a [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)  formatter on your code, something like [autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8) perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function:

```
def enemy_stats(current_enemy_health):
    if current_enemy_health<=0:
        print(current_enemy,"died.")
    if current_enemy_health>0:
        dmg=randint(0,50)
        current_enemy_health=enemy_health-dmg
        print(current_enemy,"has",current_enemy_health,"health left.")
```

You have these two lines:

```
dmg=randint(0,50)
current_enemy_health=enemy_health-dmg
```

What this essentially does is subtract a random number from the current health of the enemy, which would result in the random number you reported having. To fix this, have whatever weapon a player is using be assigned a "damage" that it does that and put that into the function as an argument. Your new function would look like this:

```
def enemy_stats(current_enemy_health, dmg):
    if current_enemy_health<=0:
        print(current_enemy,"died.")
    elif current_enemy_health>0:
        current_enemy_health=enemy_health-dmg
        print(current_enemy,"has",current_enemy_health,"health left.")
```

And would be implemented like this:

```
enemy_stats(var_for_current_enemy_health, damage_of_weapon)
```

Best of luck, and happy coding!